# EF 5 Update-Database Assistance

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Code First Data Migrations and have my development database so built up that I really don't want to start fresh again. I had deleted an old table and cannot get EF to accept any model changes due to this lingering phantom table. How can I get a clean version of my database context based on the model that's currently in place? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a "Code Second" approach and reverse engineer the model from the database. A good way to do this is to use the   [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/) for VS to do the reverse engineering. Once it is installed just right-click the project and select Entity Framework > Reverse Engineer Code First and select the relevant database in the dialog. This will generate a model in the Model folder.

I usually do this in a dummy project and then copy the files across. The model generation is actually very clean and adds some nice features like initializing ICollections to a new List in the constructor which are sometimes left out of the original Code First model.

**EDIT**
Here is an article which outlines the process  [using EF with an Existing Database](http://judeokelly.com/entity-framework-existing-sql-server-database-code-second/)

Comment: I actually wrote a short article about this but its not live yet. I will be up on Monday with more detail so I will add the link to this then.